# cross compiling for ARM in recipe

Tags: cross-compiling, beagleboneblack, bitbake

I am trying to finish the yocto-labs tutorial for beaglebone black. In the tutorial, I am asked to write recipes for the "nInvaders" game. However, I cannot cross compile it. The tutorial says  I need to cross-compile nInvaders for ARM.

ninvaders.inc:

```
SUMMARY = "Space Invader Game"

HOMEPAGE = "http://ninvaders.sourceforge.net"
SECTION = "base"
SRC_URI = "${SOURCEFORGE_MIRROR}/ninvaders-0.1.1.tar.gz"


SRC_URI[md5sum] = "97b2c3fb082241ab5c56ab728522622b"


do_compile() {
    oe_runmake
}

do_install() {
    install -d ${D}${bindir}
    install -m 0644 nInvaders ${D}${bindir}
}
```

I will be more than happy, if you help me. 
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Overriding in the "do_compile" part solves the problem.

```
do_compile() {
    oe_runmake 'CC=${CC}'
}
```